# How to save a complex shopping cart in parse database

Tags: database, database-design, parse-platform, cart, shopping-cart

How can I save a shopping cart order and order history? The items price is different according to add-ons attached with it. Can I save as an object ? or use different rows for each item and link or any better and efficient ideas. addons are kept in different class and items in different class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe,one of the possible implementations of the shopping kart is to have one class **Kart** where you save the different attributes of the shopping kart. If there are certain properties of it that won't change over time then one option is to create a class to save the shopping kart identifier alongside the attributes that don't change and then in a separate class have the pointer to the original class that represents the shopping kart (by having a pointer to the row in **Kart**) and rest of the properties that do change (for example the total, or the items).

In this separated class **SepKart**, it is a good Idea to have the attributes validSince and **validUntil**, and to have in the **beforeSave** trigger, a function that sets the **validUntil** attribute of another row in **SepKart** that points to the same shopping kart in **Kart** and doesn't have it's **validUntil** set.

In the case of the items and the order of them, a list of objects that point to the items would do it, because then, if the order changes, then just saving a new instance of it would save the new order and you would then be able to see what is the history of the shipping kart in the time *A* just by querying in **SepKart** for the row that points to the shopping kart **Kart**, has a **validSince** of a time before *A* and a **validUntil** after *A* (or **validUntil** not set).